# SQL Query Error 1087 in Stored Procedure but works fine outside the procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm using this Stored Procedure from a calling one to validate a result.
I get the values from a Table which is based on a user defined Table Type.
The error is caused through the exec-command because all pass through without it.

Fails:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [cam].[M0017TEST]
@dealRecords cam.dealDataRecords readonly,
@ruleParams cam.validationRuleParams readonly
    AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BEGIN
declare @result as cam.validationRuleResult;
declare @Status as int = 0
declare @Kaktion NVARCHAR(50)  = (select Val from @ruleParams where Name = 'Source')
declare @KAWert NVARCHAR(50) = (select Val from @ruleParams where Name = 'Equ')
declare @KA NVARCHAR(200)
declare @knr bigint = (select ID from @dealRecords)
declare @vi NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @vQuery NVARCHAR(150)
    
if @Kaktion <> ''
    Begin
        set @vQuery = concat('select @vi=',@Kaktion,' from @dealRecords'); 
        -- SQL String is fine
        EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL  
            @Query  = @vQuery
            , @Params = N'@vi Nvarchar(50) OUTPUT'
            , @vi = @vi OUTPUT

        set @KA = (SELECT @vi)
            ….
```

the result is an error 1087.

If I use it without a stored procedure, everything is fine and I get a correct result.

Works fine:

```
'''

    declare @KontT table (Val varchar(30))
    DECLARE @vi int
    DECLARE @vQuery NVARCHAR(150)
    declare @Kontoaktion nvarchar(50) = 'has_Val'
    declare @KA nvarchar(50)

    insert into @KontT(Wert)
    values('ID')

    declare @ID varchar(20) = (select Val from @KontT)

    set @vQuery = N'select top(1) @vi=' + @ID + ' from cam.tbl_ListRegelPoolProduktcode 
                  where p1 like ' + NCHAR(39) + @Kontoaktion + NCHAR(39)
        EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL 
            @Query  = @vQuery
            , @Params = N'@vi int OUTPUT'
            , @vi = @vi OUTPUT
        set @KA = (SELECT @vi)
```

I tried a lot of sets. With variables, without, with tables, without aso. but finally always the exec-command fails within the stored procedure.

Can anyone explain the difference of the behavior or give me a hint, where I'm wrong?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? That code is product specific.

Comment: It would help if you gave the exact message being displayed with that error because [1987 is particularly generic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-events-and-errors?view=sql-server-ver15#errors-1000-to-1999): "Cannot %S_MSG %S_MSG '%.*ls' on %S_MSG '%.*ls' because its %S_MSG is disabled."

Comment: Terribly sorry, it is error 1087

Comment: Please copy the error message mate :) Why do you ask us to look it up?

Comment: This is the errormessage i get.  i read the systemerror Code and Format it to my Needs.                                                                                               ERROR - Pool 4 Rule 20: call from "M0017Action" failed: error 1087 ID/Nr: 99999/217745401

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do believe that @dealRecords is a readonly table parameter that cannot be sent forward to a dynamic sql query. (as that query could try to update the data in the table).

You could replace that with a temp table. (either create it from the calling procedure or create in in this SP and insert data from @dealRecords in it). I'm assuming there are only a few rows in it so the performance impact would not be great.

*** Edit: after creating a test script i found out you can send table parameters but just add readonly. So, add a parameter to your dynamic query:

```
, @Params = N'@vi Nvarchar(50) OUTPUT, @dealRecords cam.dealDataRecords readonly'
, @vi = @vi OUTPUT,  @dealRecords = @dealRecords
```

Does this solve your issue?

Comment: Why should a "select" from a readonly Table which output is stored in a variable cause (value is correct in variable) that?   i dont forward the table, i forward the variable.  I already tried it with temptable and tablevariable. Still doesnt work.

Comment: check my edited answer regarding the missing parameter.

Comment: Yes that's it. Lot's a trees in the Wood.